# jQuery ajax on internal network (phonegap android)

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, cordova

I am working on a phonegap application which runs simple ajax requests to a rendered website, pulls down the html and reskins content locally.

A requirement is that websites on an internal network can be requested. I have connections via global ip addresses working fine, but cannot get the ajax to work on internal networks.

For example connecting to a 10.0.0.xx address will always fail. The device is connected to the same network and I can access the websites on the internal network fine in browser.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Is it for iOS, Android, or Blackberry?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you modified your domain whitelist file correctly to allow external access.

For more information about domain whitelist, check the online doc: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Hope this helps. Let me know if this works for after modifying your domain whitelist file.

---

**Example of domain whitelist configuration for iOS:**

Open your file `Cordova.plist` and check that you made the following:

**1 -** Set `OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView` to `YES`

**2 -** Right click on `ExternalHosts` -> `Add Row`

**3 -** Set the `String` value of your new added row to `*`, so you should have your new line look like this:

```
Item0                String              *
```

Normally, you would replace `*` with the external URL you want provide access to. But, to make sure that the problem really comes from the whitelist, we will use `*`.