# use phonegap android/ios for an internal network

Tags: android, jquery, ios, cordova

I want to have a page in my phonegap app to send and receive data in an internal network.
for example a local login and receive bill in a hotel only with use of its wireless network.
I already read this question and answers =>
[jQuery ajax on internal network (phonegap android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930549/jquery-ajax-on-internal-network-phonegap-android)

but im not sure it works.and i cant clearly imagine what happen if passengers use it in other networks.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use a local url to connect, something like `http://192.168.1.20/login.php`

Then your app will only work if the device is connected to the same network where you have the server with the login page